# Quicker way to get a list of the unique quarters within a date range

Tags: matlab

I am trying to get an **unique** list of quarters within a daterange (`dateStart` to `dateEnd` which are datenum).

The output should look something like this for a daterange between 01/01/2014 and 02/02/2015:

```
201401
201402
201403
201404
201501
201502
```

Currently I do the following (see code below), but it takes quite a long time to process (`0.013` seconds for `dateStart = 735173` and `dateEnd = 735538`). I believe it is because of many inefficient rules (conversion to string and then back to double).

Are there other ways, more computationally efficient, to get the desired result?

```
function dranges = yyyyqq_range(dateStart, dateEnd)
% initiates a list of the date ranges

dates       = (dateStart:dateEnd)';
datesstr    = cellstr(datestr(dates,'yyyyqq'));

datesstr    = strrep(datesstr,'Q1','01');
datesstr    = strrep(datesstr,'Q2','02');
datesstr    = strrep(datesstr,'Q3','03');
datesstr    = strrep(datesstr,'Q4','04');

datesnumb   = str2double(datesstr);
dranges     = unique(datesnumb);


end
```

Comment: What is your question? Does the code work as-is? What are you looking for here?

Comment: An improvement of the speed.

Comment: @Luis Mendo why is this off hold? My question is how I can speed up this query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function should perform much much better:

```
function dranges = yyyyqq_range_new(dateStart, dateEnd)
    dates    = (dateStart:dateEnd)';
    datesstr = sprintfc('%d0%d',[year(dates) quarter(dates)]);
    dranges  = str2double(unique(datesstr));
end
```

Here is a small benchmark over `1000` iterations:

```
ds = 735173;
de = 735538;

tic();
for i = 1:1000
    dr = yyyyqq_range(ds,de);
end
toc();

tic();
for i = 1:1000
    dr = yyyyqq_range_new(ds,de);
end
toc();

function dranges = yyyyqq_range(dateStart, dateEnd)
    dates     = (dateStart:dateEnd)';
    datesstr  = cellstr(datestr(dates,'yyyyqq'));
    datesstr  = strrep(datesstr,'Q1','01');
    datesstr  = strrep(datesstr,'Q2','02');
    datesstr  = strrep(datesstr,'Q3','03');
    datesstr  = strrep(datesstr,'Q4','04');
    datesnumb = str2double(datesstr);
    dranges   = unique(datesnumb);  
end

function dranges = yyyyqq_range_new(dateStart, dateEnd)
    dates    = (dateStart:dateEnd)';
    datesstr = sprintfc('%d0%d',[year(dates) quarter(dates)]);
    dranges  = str2double(unique(datesstr));
end
```

Whose result is:

> Elapsed time is 16.064419 seconds.
>
> Elapsed time is 0.836365 seconds.

Basically, here are my overall improvements:

1. I removed the string replacement process (which is very expensive) implementing the [quarter](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quarter.html) function, which outputs already compliant values for date quarters.
2. I used the undocumented `sprintfc` function, instead of using the [datestr](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) function, in order to obtain a faster numeric-to-literal date conversion.
3. I kept the [str2double](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) conversion, but instead of applying it to all the literal date representations, I applied it only to the [unique](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) function output, so that it must be performed on a smaller amount of strings.

An even faster version of my function can be achieved sticking to the numeric type (actually, converting the dates to string is an unnecessary step since you want numbers). Here is it:

```
function dranges = yyyyqq_range_new_num(dateStart, dateEnd)
    dates   = (dateStart:dateEnd)';
    dranges = unique((year(dates) .* 100) + quarter(dates));
end
```

It's lightning fast. Within the same benchmarking framework, it can complete the task in about `0.15` seconds.